# How to contact a random pod for one service (mutli instance of the same pod) in the same node in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, networking, devops, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I have one single node. On this node, I have 2 applications with multi instance (3 pods each)

App A want contact App B.

My issue is : App A contact all the time the same pod of App B.
I would like alternate pod (load balancing in round robin for example)
For example :
first request: AppPod3 respond
second request: AppPod1 respond
third request: AppPod2 respond

How i can do that ?

Thank you so much for your help ...
You can see below my conf of app B
I have tried to set timeoutSeconds for sessionaffinity but it's not working ...

````
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: AppB
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: AppB
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: AppB
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: AppB-container
        image: image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: AppB
  labels:
    app: svc-AppB
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: AppB
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  sessionAffinityConfig:
    clientIP:
      timeoutSeconds: 1```
````

Comment: Checkout this blog post about grpc loadbalancing: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/11/07/grpc-load-balancing-on-kubernetes-without-tears/ Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

The service should use backend pods in round robin fashion by default. You don't need sessionAffinity settings if the pods are stateless; otherwise you will be redirected to the same pod based on the source ID.

Maybe you can add logging to the pods and observe when they are accessed. Subsequent calls to the service should be redirected to pods in round robin fashion with minimal service configuration.

**Update:** this is the deployment I am using. It balances the pods as expected; each curl request sent to the service clusterip:port ends on a different pod. My k8s installation is on premise, v1.18.3.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: baseDeployment
  labels:
    app: baseApp
  namespace: nm-app1
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: baseApp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: baseApp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: baseApp
        image: local-registry:5000/baseApp
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: baseService
  namespace: nm-app1
spec:
  selector:
    app: baseApp 
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i have allready try this and it's not working like that.
I have logger on App B and I launch 40 reqs (from App A to App B) with 1 sec between call.
I have all the time logger from the same pod of App B
I use GRPC stream but, I create 40 NEW GRPC stream

Comment: What is your url in curl ? http://IP or http://baseService ?

Comment: It is ClusterIP of the baseService. In my case, `kubectl get svc -n nm-app1` would list all services with their ClusterIPs in nm-app1 namespace.

Comment: I have try your answer, it's works.
In fact, in my case, App A is a console application and it open a stream GRPC with AppB (python). The connexion is kept for few minuts. If I launch another stream (new one) GRPC with AppB, it always the same pod which be contacted by App A.
How I can contact other pods ? because if I understand, AppA contact always the same pod of AppB because, he have some stream GRPC active on this pod ..

Answer (score -1):

@user3683760 you will have to apply load balancing strategies in your deployment. Kube has bunch of choices for balancing the traffic between your services. I would suggest play around with few patterns and see what best suit your needs.